# How to solve django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to fetch some particular dates from my database and pass them in templates.
But i am getting this error:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the
> remainder: ' ent in entries' from 'for ent in entries'

my views.py:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(user=request.user)
return render(request, 'user.html', {'user':user.title(), 'time':time, 'entries':entries})
```

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

user.html:

```
 {{for ent in entries}}
            <div id="sect">
                <div id="date" name='date'>
                    {{ent.date}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{% endfor %}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a simple typo mistake you have done in here
use this

```
{% for ent in entries %}
        <div id="sect">
            <div id="date" name='date'>
                {{ent.date}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

use percentage in for loop

Comment: Ohh..i feel so stupid...thank you bro..@Kishan Parmar